# Shliach tzibur not following the shul nusach

Tags: tefilla, chazzan-prayer-leader, chabad, nuschaot

In my shul the official nusach is Chabad. The rabbi is Chabad too. Most of the congregants are not Chassidic and they are used to daven nusach Sfard or Ashkenaz. My question is: is the shliach tzibur allowed to skip paragraphs that are not in his nusach? I asked the rabbi, and he instructed me to tell the shliach tzibur myself, privately, that he's skipping. The rabbi does not want to antagonize anybody, in order to keep congregants content. When I asked the shliach Tzibur, he smiled and said to complain to the rabbi.

Comment: I was once gabbai of a shul affiliated to the Federation of Synagogues. 
One of the members who was a Sefardi wanted to lead the prayers which would have meant using our siddur but his pronounciation. I asked [Rabbi Michael Fisher](http://archive.today/2AeVk) who was the Principal Rabbi of the Federation of Synagogues what to do.

He emphasized most strongly that the main thing was to preserve the peace of the congregation. Therefore I should do nothing that would antagonise my Sefardi friend.

Comment: What about adding pesukim like "Or Chadash" and "El Chai v'Kayam"?

Comment: @Yishai I intentionally didn't add the [chabad] tag because it seems to be *lav davka*. The question can easily apply to something else, such as an often case in my shul, which is officially nusach Sfard, but occasionally has a chazzan do Eidot Hamizrach or Ashkenaz.

Comment: Probably someone who feels strongly about their nusach and will either skip or add parts should not be shliach tzibur where the nisach differs from their own